# Launch Outlook 2007 and a Word window opens

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

After upgrading from Office 2003, whenever I launch Outlook 2007 a blank Word window opens - much like it did in Outlook 2003 with Word set as my email editor.  Does anyone know how stop this from occuring?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this glitch before (relating to upgrades).  The way I fixed it was uninstalling Office 2007 and making sure Office 2003 is uninstalled as well.  It seems to be a problem with the upgrade process.  Once all the files related to either version are gone, try a fresh install of Office 2007.  This should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but this didn't resolve it.  I'm guessing there's some registry key buried somewhere that's still sticking around from Office 2003.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling with a program that scans after the install, such as Revo Uninstaller? http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html